# Disable Deselection of row from table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using angular PrimeNg and my p-table has a `[selectionMode]` of `single`. Is there a way to disable unselect behavior from a table when click or ctrl + click is performed?

I was able to do the suggestion below, but I would like to do it in a way that I don't have to define it again to other components.

Reference:
[How to disable the option to deselect a row on TurboTable component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675497/how-to-disable-the-option-to-deselect-a-row-on-turbotable-component)